# Emptying dynamically created table

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I've got a table that looks similar to the following.. at all times I want the thead & tfoot showing .. :

```
<form method='post' id='frm1'>
<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0' id='logs' width='100%'>

<thead><tr id='thead'><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th><th>Col3</th><th>Col4</th></tr></thead>
<tfoot><tr id='tfoot'><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th><th>Col3</th><th>Col4</th></tr></tfoot>

<tbody class='fbody'>";


<tr id='empty'><td colspan='4'>empty results</td>

</tbody>

</table>
</form>
```

By default the table is empty. The user is using a search field to query a database using ajax. The results are passed back and I'm using `$.each` and looping through the returned results and adding to the table using:

```
$('#logs tr:last').before('<tr><td>' + td[0] + '</td><td>' + td[1] + '</td><td>' + td[2] + '</td><td>' + td[3] + '</td></tr>');
```

This seems to work fine, but I've hit an issue..

If results are returned I need to remove the `empty` row, if no results are returned I need to show the `empty` row.

When the first search completes, the table shows its results. If I then search using new criteria, the new results are added to the table, not replacing the original, so I end up with a table show the first and second results, when for the second search it should only be the second results.

I've tried :

```
   $("#logs").find('tr').slice(1,-1).remove()
```

This clears showing the correct results, but it leaves the empty row and removes the tfoot.

Any idea how to get this working ?

Thanks

quick update..

I'm calling the jquery / ajax lookup using :

```
        $('body').on('click', '#find', function(){
        });
```

Comment: Try this $("#logs").find("tbody").empty()

Comment: That leave the previous search values in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hanlde multiple search, you should instead hide this row. So on each search, first remove all data rows:

```
$("#logs .fbody").find('tr:not(#empty)').remove();
```

And show or hide the empty one depending you get data to display or not. You could use a simple CSS rule:

```
.fbody > tr + #empty {
  display: none;
}
```

So if there is any `tr` inside `tbody` before the `#empty`, it would be hidden, otherwise it would be displayed.

Comment: Thanks this has helped. I'm hiding or showing the `empty` row as needed and removing the others, but not thead or tfoot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$("#logs").find('tr#empty').remove()
```

Comment: That just removed the 'empty' row. When I do another search the old values are still shown.

Comment: $("#logs").find("tbody").empty() should remove your previous result. Check console if you are getting any error.

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Use following:

```
$('#logs').find('tbody').html("");
```

It will clear all from tbody of table with id "logs"

For your needs, do it like this:

```js
var RESULTS_NOT_EMPTY = "";

var empty_row = "<tr id='empty'><td colspan='4'>empty results</td></tr>";

// empty table
$('#logs').find('tbody').html("");

if (RESULTS_NOT_EMPTY) {
    // append new results
  }
else {
  $('#logs').find('tbody').append(empty_row);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0' id='logs' width='100%'>

<thead><tr id='thead'><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th><th>Col3</th><th>Col4</th></tr></thead>
<tfoot><tr id='tfoot'><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th><th>Col3</th><th>Col4</th></tr></tfoot>

<tbody class='fbody'>

</tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following approach:

```
var trData = datagotFromAjaxResp;

$('#logs tbody tr').not('tr#empty').remove(); //remove previously added search result

if(trData.length > 0){
    $('tr#empty').hide(); //hide the empty row if we have result
}
else
{
    $('tr#empty').show(); //show the empty row if we don't have result
}
//attach search result if any
$.each(trData, function( index, td ) {

    $('#logs tbody tr:last').before('<tr><td>' + td[0] + '</td><td>' + td[1] + '</td><td>' + td[2] + '</td><td>' + td[3] + '</td></tr>');

});
```